# URL amigables en Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, pretty-urls

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de activar las URL amigables en Prestashop. He probado todas las soluciones que he encontrado googleando y sin resultado.

El mod_rewrite de Apache está activado, he probado a limpiar caché y forzar la compilación.

Cuando activo las URL amigables e intento navegar, por ejemplo, a la página de contacto, me sale un error 404. Sospecho que puede ser la configuración de Apache.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Gracias por compartir, llevaba unas cuantas horas con el error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me contesto a mi mismo. He encontrado la solución al problema.

Tenía un conflicto entre la configuración SSL y las URL's amigables. Os dejo la configuración de mi archivo ssl.conf para mi tienda prestashop 1.6. Lo podeis localizar dentro de `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`:

```
ServerAdmin admin@yourserver.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/your/folder/page/
ServerName yourweburl.com

Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
<Directory /path/to/your/folder/page/ >
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#   SSL Config
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourwebsslcertificate.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourwebsslcertificate.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourwebsslcertificate.cert

</VirtualHost>
```